# parallel a loop in python class

Tags: python, class, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

hey guys i'm trying to parallel a for loop in my python class and would be really grateful for your help:
my problem is that i have two classes one is for my population class and the other one is for my individuum.

the main class "Population" hast a list of individuums so basically self.population = [individuum1,individuum2,individuum3....]. so the class individuum is like a sub class of the main class Population.

i am trying to run the evaluate function which calculate the accuracy of individuum in the the population, but for that to happen i have to run the fitness function which is implemented in the individuum Class.

#this is just an example

````
class Population(object):

  self.population =[individuum_logic_circuit() for _ in range(self.pop_size)] code
  
  def evaluate(self):
    #for indi in self.population: this woks perfectly! but i need to parallel it, to make the algorithm faster 
    #    indi.fitness(result_train)
    
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)        # i tried this kind of parallelization but it didn't work because i can't call indi.fitness 
    pool.map(indi.fitness(result_train), (indi for indi in self.population))
    


class indviduum_logic_circuit(Population):

 def fitness(self,data):
    calculate fitness 
```

any one can help with that? 
thanks in advance
````

Comment: > so the class individuum is like a sub class of the main class Population.

This seems like a misunderstanding of OOP...also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: you're right, i don't know what i wrote there i wanted to say that it's inheriting the calss Population.